# How to get id in mongodb without " ObjectID" string in Html and meteor

Tags: html, mongodb

While fetching the id in mongodb i am getting ids like this.

```
    ObjectID("55545a387d55e6f2a67ff6a0")
```

Is there any way to get the id like

```
   55545a387d55e6f2a67ff6a0
```

Comment: In the mongodb shell, I pressume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to run find command then for print in html without object you can use like this way , you can use _str in your html

```
{{this._id._str}}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [**`valueOf()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) method which returns the value of the `ObjectId()` object as a lowercase hexadecimal string. This value is the str attribute of the `ObjectId()` object. Thus

```
ObjectID("55545a387d55e6f2a67ff6a0").valueOf()
```

will return the following string:

```
55545a387d55e6f2a67ff6a0
```